# Can someone explain what a portfolio is in financial math?

Tags: probability, random-variables, finance

I took mathematical probability last semester and now I am taking financial mathematics, but only probability was a pre requisite for financial math (no finance classes were required). These types of questions re confusing me because I don't quite understand financial terminology and I guess my professor thinks that we had taken finance classes in the past. Can someone explain what a portfolio is and what $V(O)$, $V(T)$, and $K_v$ is referring to in this question?

> Let $A(0)=90$, $A(T)=100$, $S(0)=25$ dollars and let
>     $$S(T) =
> \begin{cases}
> 30,  & \text{with probability } p \\
> 20, & \text{with probability } 1-p
> \end{cases}$$
>
> where $0 < p < 1$. For a portfolio with $x=10$ shares and $y=15$ bonds, calculate $V(0)$, $V(T)$, and $K_V$.

I know what a random variable is and how to solve for expectation because I learned that in probability, but I just don't know what these finance terms are refering to?

Comment: Well, it isn't entirely clear...but it seems probable that $A(t)$ denotes the price of the bond at time $t$ (there is no uncertainty in its future value), while $S(t)$ denotes the price of the stock (very uncertain value going forward).   A portfolio is a collection of positions in the available instruments (here $15$ bonds and $10$ shares of the stock) and $V(t)$ is the value of the portfolio (so $V(0)=15*A(0)+10*S(0)=15*90+10*25$).  No guess on $K_v$.

Comment: I think satish ramanathan is wrong because e is discounting stock prices using risk-neutral probabilities when they should be discounted using real world probabilities (p, 1-p)

Comment: You can try [Quant SE](http://quant.stackexchange.com/) ?

Comment: A portfolio is just a combination of investments.  In your case you have some probability distribution of returns on shares and some other distribution of returns on bonds.  You are asked to compute something about the probability distribution of 10 shares plus 15 bonds.  You gave us no reference for shares, bonds, $x$, or $y$.

Comment: @RossMillikan Probability distribution of what?

Comment: The definitions of $V(O)$ (should it be $V(0)?, V(T), K_v$ should be given in your book. The probability distributions are likely the returns on the portfolio.  A key point is that mixed portfolios have lower variance than pure ones, which many people prefer.

Comment: @RossMillikan I seem to recall a finance question used as an example for expected value when I took elementary probability. Our first finance class was the semester after we took elementary probability Perhaps it's not given in their book but given by the prof who 'thinks that' they 'had taken finance classes in the past. '

Comment: Thank you for all of your answers, I think I understand how to get the answer and what it means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that @BCLC is right on saying that I have used risk neutral information

The Edited Answer is

$ V(0) = 15\times90+ 10\times25 = 1600$

Now compute V(T)

$$V(T) = 1800, \text{     if stock goes up}$$

$$1800 = 30\times 10 + 100\times 15$$

$$V(T) = 1700, \text{     if stock goes down}$$

$$1700 = 20\times 10 + 100\times 15$$

$V(T) = 15\times A(T) + 10\times S(T)$ where SS(T) = 30 or 20

hence the return on the portfolio is defined as

$$K_V = \frac{V(t)-V(0)}{V(0)}$$

So $$K_V = .125, \text{     if stock goes up}$$
$$K_V = .0625, \text{     if stock goes down}$$

Thus $K_V$ is 12.5% or 6.25%.

Comment: You're assuming that this is a [one-step binomial model](http://www.math.utah.edu/~zhu/5760.12f/chapter03.pdf)?

Comment: Wait, you're using risk-neutral probabilities to discount stock prices? If so, I believe that you are incorrect. Risk-neutral probabilities are for discounting derivative payoffs not stock prices.

Comment: @BCLC, I am wrong on using risk neutral valuation and I had to do it because p is not given.  But then the solution could be written in the fashion that I have (there is a solved example in the internet).  By giving paired answers, you may provide the solution as this.

Comment: upvoted. any idea if $K_V$ really refers to simple return and not log return?

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be two times here. $t=0$ and $t=T$.

A portfolio is a collection of financial instruments. For instance, I could have a portfolio consisting of 3 stocks and 1 bond. Its value today is the sum of the individual values of the instruments today.

$V(0)$ is the value of the portfolio at time 0 (today?)

$V(T)$ is the value of the portfolio at time T (at maturity?)

$A(0)$ is the value of some instrument/s (bond/s?) in the portfolio at time 0 (today?)

$A(T)$ is the value of some instrument/s (bond/s?)  in the portfolio at time T (at maturity?)

I'm guessing bonds because that is what is stated later on. So, we might have:

$V(0) = S(0)x + A(0)y = 25*10 + 90*15$

$V(T) = S(T)x + A(T)y = S(T)*25 + 100*15$

$S(T)$ is random so that's the most we can do.

However,

$E[V(T)] = E[S(T)]*25 + 100*15$

where $E[S(T)] = 30p + 20(1-p) = 10p + 20$

[This book](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=StmHmZbgtTwC&pg=PA73&lpg=PA73&dq=finance%20kv%20portfolio&source=bl&ots=6Z3HQvK7_i&sig=69jRV6d8HQEcyISlz8lbj_Y81lQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjp9_um6uTKAhWIppQKHb1xAd8Q6AEIPDAG#v=onepage&q=finance%20kv%20portfolio&f=false) suggests $K_V$ is the return on the portfolio ([simple return? log return?](http://www.portfolioprobe.com/2010/10/04/a-tale-of-two-returns/)). We might have:

$$K_v = \frac{V(T) - V(0)}{V(0)}$$

$$ = \frac{(S(T)*25 + 100*15) - (25*10 + 90*15)}{25*10 + 90*15}$$

Also random. However, we can calculate the [expected (simple?) return](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=4xfyBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA98&lpg=PA98&dq=finance%20kv%20portfolio&source=bl&ots=1xfPGLnt9A&sig=mOJ1UfiJJHFgH0qykdzhXPGSZTQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjp9_um6uTKAhWIppQKHb1xAd8Q6AEIODAF#v=onepage&q=finance%20kv%20portfolio&f=false):

$$E[K_v] = \frac{E[V(T)] - V(0)}{V(0)}$$

$$ = \frac{(E[S(T)]*25 + 100*15) - (25*10 + 90*15)}{25*10 + 90*15}$$

In case you're computing log returns, be careful:

$$E[\ln X] \ne \ln E[X]$$

See more:

1. [Jensen's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Measure-theoretic_and_probabilistic_form)
2. [NNT](http://qr.ae/RO95XV)
3. [More NNT](https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=10153004444283375&id=13012333374)

P.S. [NNT's account](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/88078/nero)